Extract top level hierarchy
The Catalog table in the ReportServer database contains a Path statement composed of hierarchical levels to  a report name. For instance:
/DW Reports/DB1/SalesReport
/Main System Reports/IT/IT Report1

might be values in the column. I'd like a script that extracts all the characters up to the 2nd slash (You'll notice that the first slash precedes all other characters in the report. I've already used a mixture of substring and charindex, but to no avail.
Tried the following but it didn't work
Select Substring(path, 2, Charindex('/',Path, 2) - 2) AS toplevelhierarchy
from catalog
where path <> '' or path is not null


The first conditional expression is useless: a '' (empty string) path is also not null. Probably you want and instead of or.

Also: we need to know what kind of database you're using. Oracle? MySQL? Sql Server? They all have different ways to handling this.

Assuming you are using sql server database , the below logic works
SELECT SUBSTRING('/DW Reports/DB1/Salesreport', 1, 
  CHARINDEX('/', '/DW Reports/DB1/Salesreport',  2) - 1) as toplevelhierarchy 

I used to 1 at the subtring so that you can get all the characters upto the 2nd '/'

Thanks for all the help. The path and Name field contained criteria that I didn't want to include, so I dealt with it all in a cte, and then extracted from that. I mucked about with adding other fields such as Path, Charindex etc, before settling just for one column output.
With Leadingslashremoved (path)
as (
Select SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(max),Path),2,len(Path)-1)
from catalog
where Path <> '' and  Path is not null and [name] <> 'System Resources'
)
Select distinct
--[Path] as FullPath
--,CHARINDEX('/', path) as CharindexNumber
--,len([Path])-CHARINDEX('/',path) as Lengthtoslash
--,CHARINDEX('/',path) - (len(path)-CHARINDEX('/',[Path]))
SUBSTRING(path,0,CHARINDEX('/',path)) as TopLevel

from leadingslashremoved
Where SUBSTRING(path,0,CHARINDEX('/',path)) <> ''
Order by toplevel 

